# How does text-to-speech shortcut read any highlighted text?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am trying to develop a cocoa application that requires to read highlighted text from any application. But so far I cannot find any decent solution because the accessibility API isn't always work. (e.g. Firefox) Does anyone know how it is implemented in text-to-speech included in Leopard?

I have found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487175/how-to-obtain-the-selected-text-from-another-application) but it isn't solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [Service](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html), so anywhere that an application identifies its selection as text, the text-to-speech service will work.

Comment: Why doesn't it appear in the service menu?