# Obtaining the currently selected text in front-most application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to obtain the selected text from another application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487175/how-to-obtain-the-selected-text-from-another-application)

How can I obtain the currently selected text in the front-most app (even if it's a different app than mine)? Are there any Public APIs to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000101i) may be what you want, though the user has to choose your service through the service menu, or contactual menu.